# Method call after returning Mono<Void>

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to call the method when previous returned `Mono<Void>`:

```
 @Override
 public Mono<Void> sendEmail(EmailDto emailDto) {
 return mailReactiveClient.sendEmail(message ->
     createMessage(emailDto, emailDto.getBody(), message))
       .doOnNext(saveNotificationLog(emailDto)); //it's not work
}

  private void saveNotificationLog(EmailDto emailDto) {
    notificationLogReactiveRepository.save(NotificationLog.builder()
       ...
      .build());
  }
```

Method `sendEmail`returns `Mono<Void>`.

So how to call `saveNotificationLog`?

**UPD:** Tring to make my question simplier:

```
 @Override
 public Mono<Void> sendEmail(EmailDto emailDto) {
 return mailReactiveClient.sendEmail(message ->
     createMessage(emailDto, emailDto.getBody(), message))
       .doOnNext(System.out.print("Hello world!"); 
}
```

How to call `doOnNext`or similar method after `sendEmail` return `Mono<Void>`?

Comment: Is `notificationLogReactiveRepository` blocking?

Comment: no, it's store NotificationLog obj in DB and return Mono<NotificationLog>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`doOnNext`, and in general all `doOn*` reactor methods are side-effect methods. You're not supposed to call them to do I/O work or chain operations, but rather log things and not do anything that would affect the state of the application.

In your code sample, `notificationLogReactiveRepository.save` returns `Mono<Void>`. The `saveNotificationLog` returns `void` and does not subscribe to the publisher returned by `notificationLogReactiveRepository.save`. This means the notification will not be saved, because [nothing happens until you subscribe](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe).

In this case, it seems you're trying to chain operations - `then` operators are just made for that. Your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> sendEmail(EmailDto emailDto) {
    return mailReactiveClient.sendEmail(message ->
        createMessage(emailDto, emailDto.getBody(), message))
           .then(saveNotificationLog(emailDto));
}

private Mono<Void> saveNotificationLog(EmailDto emailDto) {
    return notificationLogReactiveRepository.save(NotificationLog.builder()
        ...
        .build());
}
```

Answer (score 30):

The Mono will not emit data, so `doOnNext` will not be triggered. You should use the `doOnSuccess` instead.

Also, your Mono need to be consumed. Without the code, we don't know if it is or not.

Some example here: I added `subscribe()` to consume the mono. Depending on the use of your Mono, you will have to do or not the same thing.

This print nothing:

```
Mono<String> m=Mono.just("test");
Mono<Void> v=m.then();
v.doOnNext(x->System.out.println("OK")).subscribe();
```

This print "OK":

```
Mono<String> m=Mono.just("test");
Mono<Void> v=m.then();
v.doOnSuccess(x->System.out.println("OK")).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 11):

Try it this way:

```
Mono.empty().then()
```